# Custom tooltip directive(created with Overlay and OverlayPositionBuilder) to accept ng-template as input, is not correctly handling hover event

Tags: angular, angular-material, hover, overlay, angular-directive

I am trying to create a **custom tooltip directive** that accepts **TemplateRef** as input using Material **Overlay** and **OverlayPositionBuilder**, so we can pass the **HTML template** as input and display it inside the tooltip.

This is the code simple so far:

```
 @Directive({
   selector: '[rsTooltip]',
 })
 export class RsTooltipDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;
   ...other properties
    
   private _overlayRef: OverlayRef;
    
   constructor(private _overlay: Overlay, private _overlayPositionBuilder: OverlayPositionBuilder, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}
  
   ...NgOnInit handling tooltip position, etc

   @HostListener('mouseenter')
   showTooltip() {

    if (this._overlayRef && !this._overlayRef.hasAttached()) {
      const tooltipRef: ComponentRef<CustomTooltipComponent> = this._overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(CustomTooltipComponent));
      tooltipRef.instance.contentTemplate = this.contentTemplate;
    }
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  hideTooltip() {
    if (this._overlayRef) {
      this._overlayRef.detach();
    }
  }

 ...NgOnDestroy
}
```

**CustomTooltipComponent** is a simple component(represent tooltip) that simply receives the template and renders it.

[image]

So, the issue is whenever I hover over the **host**(directive host) element, the **tooltip**(CustomTooltipComponent) is displayed, but if I try to hover over the tooltip content(CustomTooltipComponent) it is no longer visible. Is there any way to handle this situation ?  I want to update  **@HostListener('mouseleave')** so it also checks the this._overlayRef.instance hover state; if user is hovering on top of CustomTooltipComponent it should not hide the tooltip.

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz for easy debugging?

Comment: I think the tooltip hides because you leave the host element **before** hovering over the tooltip. So it’s sort of too late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure if you can check event.target

**Update**, as @Keryanie say, we should ask about `$event.toElement` instead `$event.target`.

```
  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event.target'])
```

```
  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event.toElement'])
  hideTooltip(target) {
    if (this._overlayRef &&
       !_this.overlayRef.overlayElement.contains(target)) ) {

      this._overlayRef.detach();
    }
  }
```

but you should "detach", when mouseleave the tooltip

Comment: Thanks, you gave the idea to fix it. I am reading this from event: ['$event.toElement']... and then checking this inside if condition: !this.overlayRef.hostElement.contains(target). So, I am checking where the mouse is going; if that is the tooltip component, it's not detecting the tooltip. Then as you said, I am doing the same thing for the tooltip component(if it's going to the current host component, it's not detaching the tooltip). Can you update your answer with what I wrote(for other people)?

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem. Nothing I found online seemed to help, until I noticed that the backdrop also triggers mouse events, so I just removed it from the OverlayConfig object used for initialization.